# parsing sql statement in haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm novice to haskell

How to parse sql statement "select a from b where a in (value1,value2,value3,...);" using haskell

I'm referring http://hpaste.org/76009 for parsinng sql statement

Answer (score 1):

It's using the [parsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec) package to do the parsing. You will need to `import Text.Parsec`, then

```
case
    parse p_sql "filename for error messages"
        "select a from b where a in (value1,value2,value3,...);"
  of
    Left parseError  -> -- handle the error
    Right statements -> -- do something with your parsed sql statements
```